# Losing decimal when doing array operation in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to make a function and inside it there is a code to divides a column with its column sum and here I come up with.

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])
print(A)
A = A.T
Asum = A.sum(axis=1)
print(Asum)
for i in range(len(Asum)):
    A[:,i] = A[:,i]/Asum[i]
```

I'm hoping some decimal matrix but it automatically turn into integer. It gives me a zero matrix. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: `A` is created as an interger array.  The first print shows that.

Answer (score 0):

You must change:

```
Asum = A.sum(axis=1)
```

by:

```
Asum = A.sum(axis=0)
```

To get the column by column sum.
Also you can get the division easily with [`numpy.divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html):

```
np.divide(A, Asum)
#array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
#       [0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
#       [0.3, 0.3, 0.3],
#       [0.4, 0.4, 0.4]])
```

Or simply with:

```
A/Asum
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `A` is integer dtype; assigned floats get truncated.  If `A` started as a float array your iteration would work.  But you don't need to iterate to perform this calculation:

```
In [108]: A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]).T
In [109]: A
Out[109]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
In [110]: Asum = A.sum(axis=1)
In [111]: Asum
Out[111]: array([ 3,  6,  9, 12])
```

`A` is (4,3), `Asum` is (4,).  If we make it (4,1):

```
In [114]: Asum[:,None]
Out[114]: 
array([[ 3],
       [ 6],
       [ 9],
       [12]])
```

we can perform the divide without iteration (review `broadcasting` if necessary):

```
In [115]: A/Asum[:,None]
Out[115]: 
array([[0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333]])
```

`sum` has `keepdims` parameter that makes this kind of calculation easier:

```
In [117]: Asum = A.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
In [118]: Asum
Out[118]: 
array([[ 3],
       [ 6],
       [ 9],
       [12]])
```